# How do you make nested models in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I've recently started working with Java, Spring MVC, JPA and Hibernate and have set up a basic project structure.

I have the following scenario with two models:

- University model, with properties:

  - name
  - [...]
  - location_id
  - location (typed as instance of Location class)
- Location model, with properties:

  - city
  - state
  - [etc]

The data is retrieved via JPA repositories. I need to emulate a very simple join between the two "tables", so basically I need to:
- exclude the location property of the University model, because there'll be no column in the "table" to hold that data
- tell the JPA repository responsible for retrieving the universities that, for each university, it must retrieve the location object according to the location_id

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: use lazy load on the university-location association

Comment: Yeah, lazy or eager is not the issue, the point is I don't know how to tell the repository to fetch them in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, quick answer for the location property in the University model is:

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="locationId")
private Location location;
```

That will tell Hibernate to have a property called location, which is typed as an instance of Location, but is represented as a different column in the "table", column that holds only the id.

More explanations here: http://levelup.lishman.com/hibernate/associations/many-to-one.php